# how to call one rule from anothe rule or how to use recursive in drools

Tags: drools, drools-guvnor

```
import com.scheme.scheme_s1;

rule "slab 1 FOR E15-RETGOOMZ_AS"
   when
      item3 : scheme_s1 (slabamount>=160001 && slabamount<=460000)

   then
       item3.setOFFVALUE(420);
   end 

rule "slab 2 FOR E15-RETGOOMZ_AS"
   when
      item3 : scheme_s1 (slabamount>=55001 && slabamount<=160000)

   then
       item3.setOFFVALUE(120);
   end

rule "slab 3 FOR E15-RETGOOMZ_AS"
   when
      item3 : scheme_s1 (slabamount>=0 && slabamount<=55000)
   then
      item3.setOFFVALUE(30);
   end
```

in above code suppose the slab amount =360000 then first rule will fire. but after that rule I want to check again for slabamount is 360000-160000(lower range of that rule). then again this rule will fire with slabamount 200000. after that again I want to check slabamount 200000-160000 . then 3rd rule will fire with slab amount 40000.
how can I do this recursive . or how can I  call 1 rule from another rule.
what is the way ..
please help

Comment: please help me to do this recursive

Comment: So are you saying each time slabamount changes, you want the criteria in a rule to change? i.e. (slabamount>=160001 && slabamount<=[new slabamount value] )

Comment: no when the slab amount will be changed .. the rule will be fire for new updated slab amount.i got the solution .using UPDATE keyword I done this. thank you.